# boost::asio UDP send/receive in the same process

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I've written some asio-based networking classes, and they work as expected as long as they are run in separate processes.  In the process of improving my test coverage, I've run into a case where the receiver will usually stop receiving data.  Since my (CxxTest) test suite is a single application,

I've thrown the code up [here, in a gist](https://gist.github.com/nickveys/6357523), it's pretty short, but the "gist" of it is:

```
create endpoint (127.0.0.1:54321, shared by rx/tx)
create service
create tx socket
  open
  set reusable(true)
  set broadcast(true)
create rx socket
  open
  bind to endpoint
  async_receive...
create thread(io_service::run)

send data several times
wait a few seconds

io_service::stop
thread::join
```

My `receive` function just dumps the new data into a vector and stores it, it also barks out a print statement with how many bytes it received.  When I run this, I get 1 `receive` call with an expected amount of data, sometimes I get 2, and **very** rarely I've gotten 3.

Now, when I rip this file in half, one only doing the transmit side, the other only doing the receive side, it works great.  Absolutely no changes other than removing each part's irrelevant contributions.

I have watched in WireShark, and all of the transmits are happening as expected, and since they're supposed to be synchronous, that makes sense to me.  It's as if the receive handler isn't seeing anything new come in, so it just sits quietly.  How am I missing the data?  I'm new to asio, so I hope I'm just doing something obviously dumb!

Comment: In addition to the threading problem, the code invokes platform specific behavior (which may be unspecified).  Consider checking system documentation for dispatch behavior when delivering a unicast datagram to an address on which multiple sockets are bound.  It is akin to having two mailboxes for a single street address.  The postal service delivers a letter, randomly selecting a mailbox to place it in.  If you always check the same box, you may miss a letter.  For well-defined behavior, consider using a unique address per socket or one-to-many communication (i.e. broadcast or multicast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK second try :D but this time I checked it.

Your problem is that you are using the same endpoint for send and receive. Also I found [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html):

> In general, it is safe to make concurrent use of distinct objects, but unsafe to make concurrent use of a single object. However, types such as io_service provide a stronger guarantee that it is safe to use a single object concurrently.

So create one endpoint for your `txsock` and one for `rxsock` -> sending to send_end/ receiving from rec_end I got this result.

```
send(2006)
receive(2006)
receive(2006)
send(2006)
receive(2006)
send(2006)
receive(2006)
send(2006)
send(2006)
receive(2006)
receive(2006)
send(2006)
send(2006)
receive(2006)
receive(2006)
send(2006)
received 8 packet(s) total
receive(0)
receive error: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
...
```

```cpp
ba::ip::udp::endpoint send_end;
ba::ip::udp::endpoint rec_end;

send_end = ba::ip::udp::endpoint(address, 54321);
rec_end = ba::ip::udp::endpoint(address, 54321);

// ...

rxsock->bind(rec_end);
// in go and receive
rxsock->async_receive_from(ba::buffer(buffer, BUF_SZ), rec_end,
    boost::bind(receive, ba::placeholders::error, ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

// ...
std::size_t sz = socket.send_to(b.data(), send_end);
```

- While testing I found out that if I replace the `async_receive_from` by `async_receive` it also works (on my machine) without adding an endpoint.
- It also works if I replace `send_to` by `send` and connect the txsock to the endpoint.

Comment: I'm with you on the UDP packets possibly being lost, but I don't think that's the case.  I can deliberately sleep in the `receive` function to slow it wayyy down, and I still always receive the data when running in separate processes.  Slowing down the `send`'s doesn't help either.  Adding an index to the packet, I always receive the first packet, and any other packets have *always* been sequential (no gaps) in the 100-or-so runs I've done so far.

Comment: @NickVeys i tried something out and it is running on my machine.

Comment: Interesting! I'll give it a shot, thanks for going the extra mile.

Comment: Looks like it took care of it, getting all the data now.  Thanks!